# Plasma system tray "Updates" widget incorrect

Tags: kubuntu, system-tray, plasma-5, widgets

Kubuntu 18.04, KDE Plasma 5.12.9

For several weeks now, the "Updates" widget in my system tray is off by one. When I see the blue ball on the icon in the system tray and click on it, if it claims there to be 1 package to update, when I click the "Update" button, Discover boots up, gronks away, and finally tells me "No updates". Synaptic agrees with Discover.

The box has been rebooted a few times but no change. Is there something I can do to fix the widget? Or, is there an alternative to it?

Comment: do you have any flatpaks installed?

Comment: If you have any flatpaks installed, this is a bug in Plasma.  see if this Q&A helps:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174173/why-does-kubuntu-19-04-show-an-update-that-apparently-doesnt-exist

Comment: let me know if the answer I lined to helped and I will update it to include 18.04 as definitely affected by this bug

Comment: @TrailRider, I feel you can change "Why does Kubuntu 19.04 show an update that apparently doesn't exist?" to "Why do some versions of Kubuntu show an update that apparently doesn't exist?" Then, you can modify the Q&A as you feel necessary.

Comment: @TrailRider, if you make your suggestion an answer, I will happily mark it as the solution!

Comment: @DKBose I was planning on doing that if it worked for the OP.  When I posted my solution I was only sure that 19.04 was affected so I didn't make it any broader, now that I know that it works on other versions for sure I will edit the title..I did put a note in there about other version in case someone was having the issue on other versions.

Comment: @granti128 if the post I linked worked for you then the best thing you can do is upvote both my Q and A and if you want to put a comment in my answer to verify it works with 18.04 to be verify for then next user that it worked.  I'm going to chance the title of my OP to be more broad and we will mark you question as a duplicate to point everyone to  my previos answer rather than have multiple answers, it keeps the sight cleaner. and your upvotes show that the answer is reliable and upvoteing the question makes show up higher in the next persons search

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Kubuntu show an update that apparently doesn't exist? / Why is my update notification incorrect?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174173/why-does-kubuntu-show-an-update-that-apparently-doesnt-exist-why-is-my-updat)