# Ubuntu Updater icon says 3 updates, but can't find any

Tags: kubuntu, snap, update-manager, flatpak

Muon finds no updates.

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade finds no updates.

sudo apt-get install -f doesn't do anything.

The Ubuntu Updater icon says there are 3 updates, but when it searches for them, it doesn't find any, but the icon stays in my panel.

There's a transitory error message saying something about kednlive, but it goes away before I can read all of it. kdenlive was installed, but is not installed now.

I think this may have started after I installed a flatpak for the newest version of kcalc.

```
bigbird@sananda:~
$ flatpak list
Name                             Application ID                               Version         Branch            Installation
Mesa                             org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default          21.1.8          20.08             system
Mesa                             org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default          21.3.8          21.08             system
Intel                            org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel                         20.08             system
Intel                            org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel                         21.08             system
openh264                         org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264            2.1.0           2.0               system
Breeze Gtk theme                 org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Breeze-Dark                                3.22              system
KDE Application Platform         org.kde.Platform                                             5.15              system
KDE Application Platform         org.kde.Platform                                             5.15-21.08        system
KCalc                            org.kde.kcalc                                22.04.0         stable            system
bigbird@sananda:~
```

How can I fix this so I know when real updates are available?

Is there a way to run whatever that icon launches from a terminal where there might be more messages?

kubuntu 18.04.

```
$ sudo fwupdmgr refresh
Fetching metadata https://cdn.fwupd.org/downloads/firmware.xml.gz
Downloading…             [***************************************]
Fetching signature https://cdn.fwupd.org/downloads/firmware.xml.gz.asc

bigbird@sananda:~/pq
```

Finally took a picture of my screen with my phone and got this message before it disappeared:

```
kdenlive projectprofile knsrc: Loading of providers from file https://kdenlive.org/data/mltprofilesources.xml failed
```

I found this [answer](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/plasma-discover-loading-providers-failed.html) and did a `sudo rm -f /etc/xdg/kdenlive*` which got rid of that error message, but didn't affect the rest of the problem.

```
locate -b kdenlive
```

gets a ton of hits, mostly in flatpak and in snap, but almost all of them are png and svg icons, etc.

Deleted `~/.config/kdenliverc`, but that didn't make a difference.

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/kdenlive
```

got rid of a bunch of files, but didn't help otherwise.

Just rebooted and updater icon in panel persists.

Comment: Does `sudo apt full-upgrade` work?

Comment: What gives `sudo fwupdmgr refresh`  maybe firmware updates.

Comment: @Terrance sudo apt full-upgrade does nothing. I think that's what Muon does under the GUI hood.

Comment: @nobody haven't seen that one before. It did something, but didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: does `fwupdmgr get-updates` show any updates?

Comment: Sorry, there is a bug about this that wasn't fixed until 19.10  https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=385754 and see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174173/why-does-kubuntu-show-an-update-that-apparently-doesnt-exist-why-is-my-updat

Comment: @Terrance That "fixed" it. If you make it an answer, I will upvote it. Thanks.